# char[] -> String -> bytes[] -> String... and I'm lost

Tags: java, hash, sha

What I'm trying to do is to convert a password typed into a jPasswordField into SHA-256 hash. I was wandering around and found how to do this if I've got password saved as a string but the field I'm using is returning char[] so I ended up just guessing what to do... at first I've got different results even if the password was the same but now I believe I'm closer as it's a constant; but it's still not it as the output of

```
echo -n 'abc' | sha256sum
```

is

> ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad

while the output of my action (for the same input) is

> 86900f25bd2ee285bc6c22800cfb8f2c3411e45c9f53b3ba5a8017af9d6b6b05

My action looks like this:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgorithmException = null;
        MessageDigest messageDigest = null;
        try {
            messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            noSuchAlgorithmException = ex;
        }
        if (noSuchAlgorithmException != null) {
            System.out.println(noSuchAlgorithmException.toString());
        }
        else {
            UnsupportedEncodingException unsupportedEncodingException = null;
            byte[] hash = null;
            char[] password = jPasswordField1.getPassword();
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            for (char c : password) {
                if (c > 0 && c < 16) {
                    stringBuffer.append("0");
                }
                stringBuffer.append(Integer.toHexString(c & 0xff));
            }
            String passwordString = stringBuffer.toString();
            try {
                hash = messageDigest.digest(passwordString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                unsupportedEncodingException = ex;
            }
            if (unsupportedEncodingException != null) {
                System.out.println(unsupportedEncodingException.toString());
            }
            else {
                stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                for (byte b : hash) {
                    stringBuffer.append(String.format("%02x", b));
                }
                String passwordHashed = stringBuffer.toString();
                System.out.println(passwordHashed);
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried printing what you store in `passwordString`?

Comment: Why are you hex-encoding the password before hashing? (The `for (char c : password)` loop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much nailed it.  just took the hard/wrong way converting from `char[]` to `String` -> `new String(password)` is all you need.  (hint, if you find yourself manually converting between bytes and chars, you're probably doing it wrong).

as a side note, exceptions are "thrown" for a reason.  that makes it easy to skip the following code which shouldn't be executed when the exception is thrown.  by catching and turning the exceptions into "if" blocks, you make the code more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Okay, basically I can't understand your advice... to make something coded by SHA-256 I need to .digest(bytes[]) this and to get bytes[] from a char[] I need to make it a String in the middle... the final String is just to print it. Could you present the idea in some other way? About catches - yeah, I will change that, I just don't really understand them jet and I'm not using them generally...

Comment: @SzymonM.Sabat - you misunderstand.  your `String` -> `byte[]` conversion is just fine, i was just correcting first the `char[]` -> `String` conversion.

Comment: so how should char[] -> String (or maybe char[] -> bytes[]) look like?

Comment: @SzymonM.Sabat - that's already answered in the second sentence of my answer.

Comment: Okay, made it with:
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            for (char c : password) {
                stringBuffer.append(Character.toString(c));
            }
            String passwordString = stringBuffer.toString();

Thanks!

Comment: @SzymonM.Sabat - what didn't you understand about `new String(password)`?

Comment: Indeed.  This should be a single line, just calling the `String` constructor, not dealing with `StringBuffer` random cruft.  (Ideally, of course, there should be charsets mentioned explicitly every time you convert to/from a `byte[]`,  but that's another story.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman - a charset _is_ used at the place where a String is converted to a byte[], "UTF-8".  that part is correct.

Comment: Ah, see it now.  I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

This prints out the same hash as `sha256sum`

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    char[] password = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'};

    MessageDigest messageDigest = null;
    messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

    byte[] hash = null;

    // This is how you convert a char array into a String without reencoding it into a different set of characters.
    String passwordString = new String(password);

    hash = messageDigest.digest(passwordString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : hash) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    String passwordHashed = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(passwordHashed);
}
```